# R dataframe random fill

Tags: r

How can I make this dataframe larger ?

```
val = c(3, 8, 15) 
var = c("x","x","x") 
df = data.frame(var,val)
```

multiplying the var object by length(val)
and randomly assigning values to val

can this be accomplished using:

```
data.frame(???)[3:2,]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
# chose the number of rows your DF should have
N <- 30

# Let's say you want the numbers to be between 1 and 100
val <- sample(1:100, N, replace = T)

# You chosed to name them all 'x' and repeat this N times
var <- rep('x', N)

# make data.frame
df <- data.frame(val,var)

# show the first 10 rows
df[1:10,]
#>    val var
#> 1   81   x
#> 2   31   x
#> 3   33   x
#> 4   18   x
#> 5   29   x
#> 6   66   x
#> 7   16   x
#> 8    9   x
#> 9   35   x
#> 10  33   x
```